# Не работает useState

Tags: reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Несколько дней не могу понять в чем проблема. Пишу ToDo лист, в котором должна быть функция удаления некоторых элементов по нажатию кнопки. Пишу useState, и он не удаляет. Почему то не работает setState. Если вывожу в консоль copy, то показывает что элементы массива удаляются, но если же вывожу сам st, то он вообще не меняется. Вот сам код:

```js
const data = [
        {
            title: "Finish essay collaboration",
            isCompleted: false,
            id: 1
        },
        {
            title: "Read next chapter of the book",
            isCompleted: false,
            id: 2
        },
        {
            title: "Send the finished assignment",
            isCompleted: false,
            id: 3
        },]
const ToDo = ()=>{

    const [st, setSt] = useState(data)
    const del = (id)=>{
        const copy = [...st]
        const current = copy.filter(t=> t.id !==id)
        setSt(current)
        console.log(current)
    }
```

Comment: Покажите фото того, что выводится в консоли, так будет легче понять

Comment: Вот, добавил скрин. При нажатии на кнопку, в консоли показывает что один элемент массива удалился, и их осталось 2, но при этом на экране остались все 3 элемента, потому что setSt не перезаписал сам массив data

Comment: а где-то код можно глянуть полностью? GitHub, или может на CodePen закинете?

Comment: это на данный момент практически весь код. Есть еще один компонент с кнопкой. Но проблема не в ней, кнопка сама работает, в консоль выводит копию массива, а вот setSt почему то сам массив не перезаписывает

Comment: в текущем виде сложно увидеть, что конкретно не так, но возможно у вас не происходит перерендер (перерисовка) компонента. Попробуйте использовать хук useEffect

Comment: https://github.com/shumakoffnick/firstReact Вот, добавил все файлы по проекту на гит

Comment: @Николай `setSt` меняет `st`, а при рендере вы мапите `data`, `data` - это первоначальный неизменяемый массив. надо `<>{st.map(d=><ToDoItem key={d.id} da={d} del={del}/>)}</>`

Comment: И вам спасибо, просто во вложенном комментарии увидел не сразу!)

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть массив **data** - он не меняется. Также есть состояние **st**, которое принимает значение data. Соответственно, при фильтрации удаляются элементы из самого состояния, а массив **data** остается нетронутым. Нужно делать цикл по изменяемому состоянию, а не неизменяемому объекту:

```
return (
    <>
        {st.map(d=><ToDoItem key={d.id} da={d} del={del}/>)} 
    </>
)
```

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо!) Все заработало!

Comment: Справедливости ради, Дмитрий Козлов сказал это даже немного раньше меня. Но я был рад помочь)